# Assigning row as column header

Tags: excel, automation, rpa, uipath

I have an excel sheet with a format like this:

```
Header 1
subheader1|subheader2|subheader3|
data      | data     |data      |
Header 2
subheader4|subheader5|subheader6|
data      | data     |data      |
```

After filtering i'm left with:

```
subheader4|subheader5|subheader6|
data      | data     |data      |
```

but when i try to filter by columns the header disappeared and only left with the data itself in the datatable/new excel sheet i copied to. If i checked the add header option when read and write range, it shows only the default "column0","column1" etc

How do i make it so that the sub headers remains after filtering,or changing the column header to row 1 which is the sub header?

Comment: Move the second header to another Sheet would be the best solution.

Comment: @kwoxer disagree

Answer (score 0):

You have to format your data differently.

Excel filters do not work with subheaders and they hate empty rows.

For your format, all you need to do is create a column that contains your Headers.

You have this right now...

```
Header 1
subheader1|subheader2|subheader3|
data      | data     |data      |
Header 2
subheader4|subheader5|subheader6|
data      | data     |data      |
```

And you didn't turn it into this...

```
Header 1|subheader1|subheader2|subheader3|
Header 1|data      | data     |data      |
Header 2|subheader4|subheader5|subheader6|
Header 2|data      | data     |data      |
```

This should be very easy to do by loading your data into PowerQuery and unpivoting the first column.

Once you've done that, you're free to use filters, pivot tables, etc.

---

If you're looking to get...

```
Header 1  |Header1   |Header1   |
subheader1|subheader2|subheader3|
data      | data     |data      |
Header 2  |Header2   |Header2   |
subheader4|subheader5|subheader6|
data      | data     |data      |
```

Load your data into PowerQuery, do not check the " my data includes headers" checkbox

Transpose once

Select the columns with the main headers, and click fill down

Transpose again

Promote the 1st row to headers if desired

Comment: changing the format still doesn't prevent the filter data table activity from removing my subheaders, i need a way to change the default column headers (column0,column1 etc) to that of the subheaders, particularly the 2nd set of data which is subheader 4 onwards

Comment: @Soh Zheng Wei check my update, is that the pattern you're trying to match?

Comment: This is not a solution for UiPath as I can see.

Comment: @kwoxer re: UI Path, a fair point, I know nothing about it. Up to this point, I thought OP wanted to retain the full table, it looks as though I can't read and only the second half is significant.